# Is there a limit to the number of aliases for a given openshift application?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I need to alias these and more domains:

```
rhc alias add myapp www.abc.com
rhc alias add myapp www.xyz.com
```

etc. etc.

**Question:**

Is there a limit to the number of aliases for a given openshift application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked around on the engineering team and no one is aware of any limits when adding aliases to an application.